# Anuncio de Admob bonificado en aplicación Android. Las peticiones de los usuarios no generan impresiones

Tags: java, android, admob

Es mi primera aplicación a ver si me pueden ayudar por favor que en los grupos de Google no me contestan.

Tengo una aplicación Android escrita en Java a la que puse un anuncio bonificado por monedas para usar la aplicación usando la red de publicidad Admob. Tuve que quitar el sistema de monedas y poner solo intersticiales y banner que funcionan correctamente pese a no haber iniciado ninguna mediación.

He seguido para los bonificados la [guía de implementación de la API nueva](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-fullscreen?hl=es). Mi mosqueo empieza cuando recibo por email instrucciones de implementación, y ponen link a la [API vieja](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video?hl=es). ¿Cuál de las dos API he de implementar?

Por otra parte inicio la mediación, y subo una actualización con un botón para ver el anuncio bonificado y obtener las monedas, y otro para obtener monedas gratis. Solo me ha aceptado la red Chocolate, el resto rechazado.

Lleva una semana publicada así, y todos los días, mis primeros 500 usuarios clican 10 o 20 veces y en Admob me sale que recibo esas peticiones y que la tasa de respuesta es del 100% , y solo se imprimen 1 o 2 anuncios. He tenido que quitar el anuncio porque no se podía usar la app sin monedas.

Por otra parte, recibo un rechazo de una mediación en la que me pregunta por mi tráfico y me dice que no va a poder ofrecerme el servicio porque no me generaría tráfico de anuncios suficiente.

¿He entendido bien? ¿Significa eso que como solo tengo una app con solo 500 usuarios no puedo operar con Admob con anuncios bonificados?
¿En Facebook me pasaría lo mismo? Los anuncios intersticiales y banner me funcionan correctamente sin haber iniciado ninguna mediación, pero no el bonificado.

Mi código de implementación por si he programado algo mal  es el siguiente. Con el id de prueba funciona.

build.graddle (module)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.5.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-my-app-id"/>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
    });
}
```

Shop.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    RewardedAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-my-rewarded-ad-id",
            adRequest, new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                    // Handle the error.
                    mRewardedAd = null;
                }
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd rewardedAd) {
                    mRewardedAd = rewardedAd;
                    mRewardedAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Called when ad is shown.
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                            // Called when ad fails to show.
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Called when ad is dismissed.
                            // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
                            mRewardedAd = null;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    Button btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (mRewardedAd != null) {
            Activity activityContext = Shop.this;
            mRewardedAd.show(activityContext, new OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
                    daCoinsAdd();
                }
            });
        } else {
            switch (languaje) {
                case "es": {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No cargó el anuncio.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    break;
                }
                case "it": {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Non ha caricato l'annuncio.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    break;
                }
                case "fr": {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Il n'a pas chargé l'annonce.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It did not load the ad.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No tiene que ver con tu pregunta, pero en vez de usar un switch para los idiomas podrías haber usado los archivos contextualizados de android para las traducciones... puedes subir 4 archivos con tus string ahí anotados, y en vez de escribir los switch tú simplemente usas `context.getString(R.string.ERROR_CARGANDO_ANUNCIO)` (por ejemplo), y android se encarga de dártela en el idioma que tenga seleccionado el usuario. Es muy práctico y te evita tener que revisar todo tu código cuando quieres cambiar una traducción, porque están todas en el mismo sitio. Suerte con la pregunta!

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto a tu pregunta acerca de que guía debes usar, lo recomendable es usar la guía que describe la versión 20 del SDK

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration?hl=es

Veo que el principal problema es que no se están generando impresiones, debes saber que si es una aplicación nueva o los ad unit usados en la misma son nuevos, deberás esperar desde unas horas hasta unos días para poder visualizar las impresiones.

Lo que debes revisar son los siguientes puntos:

1- No usar ad units de prueba ya que estos generarían trafico invalido y no se mostrarían nunca impresiones.

2.- Realiza pruebas con los anuncios de prueba para asegurar el funcionamiento:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#sample_ad_units
para el Banner e Instersticial bonificado usa los Id:

> Bonificado:    ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917
>
> Intersticial bonificado: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5354046379

si se muestran los anuncios de prueba con esto aseguras que obtendrás las impresiones al cambiar a los ad Unit de producción.

3.- En tu código te sugiero imprimas en el LogCat si existe algún error en la carga, esto sería dentro de `onAdFailedToLoad()`  :

```
  private final String TAG = "ANUNCIOS";
...
...
 adRequest, new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                    // Handle the error.
                    mRewardedAd = null;
                   Log.e(TAG, "Error al cargar anuncio " + loadAdError.getMessage()); //***Imprime mensaje!
                }
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd rewardedAd) {
                    mRewardedAd = rewardedAd;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Anuncio cargado!."); //***Imprime mensaje!
                    mRewardedAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Called when ad is shown.
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                            // Called when ad fails to show.
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Called when ad is dismissed.
                            // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
                            mRewardedAd = null;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hola. Gracias por la respuesta. El id lleva activo un mes y ha mostrado anuncios y con el id de prueba funciona también. El problema es que de 20 peticiones que recibo muestro 1 o 2 anuncios. Me corroboran de Google que mi código es correcto y no es el problema. No sé si es porque no tengo hecha la mediación. Los anuncios banner e intersticiales que he implementado sí que funcionan, así que tampoco es mi id de aplicación. Es el id de anuncio bonificado, no sé por qué. Lo he tenido que quitar.

Comment: Voy a probar con el sdk de Facebook porque en Google no me dan ninguna explicación.